# Can not find symbol

Tags: java

When I ran this program:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class DrawApplet extends JApplet{

    public void init () {

        Container content_pane = getContentPane ();
        // Create an instance of DrawingPanel
        int x=1000, y=1000;

        content_pane.setSize(x, y);

        // And add the DrawingPanel to the content pane.
        main_panel drawing_panel = new main_panel(x,y);
        content_pane.add(drawing_panel);
    }
}
```

it showed an error:

```
DrawApplet.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
main_panel drawing_panel = new main_panel(x,y);
     ^
symbol:   class main_panel
location: class DrawApplet
DrawApplet.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
main_panel drawing_panel = new main_panel(x,y);
                                    ^
symbol:   class main_panel
location: class DrawApplet
2 errors
```

Comment: You are not compiling the same code at all! Line 12 is empty!

Comment: Are you sure the code you pasted is the code that's actually being  compiled? Because it doesn't seem so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `my` a class you created?  If so, it doesn't follow typical naming standards - as classes should begin with a capital letter.  Is it on the classpath?

Furthermore, your error doesn't match the code you've posted (`my` vs. `main_panel`).  Make sure your files and your build are up-to-date.

Comment: ya... i created  'my' class . The program actually working on database.

Comment: Is main_panel declared in the same package as DrawApplet?  If not, you need an import statement.  Otherwise, make sure it is on the classpath, and that your build is up-to-date.

Comment: i declared main_panel and DrawApplet in same package and put 'import' statement. Same error..

Comment: What are you using to manage your build?  javac?  An IDE such as Eclipse?

Comment: Eclipse and Netbeans showing no error. But javac showing above error..

Comment: Please provide a complete export of the commands you're trying to run to compile and run, with the outputs included.

Comment: >javac DrawApplet.java
Then it showing above error..